# Excel: Alternate the color of each cell change?

Tags: excel, formatting

How to alternate the color of each cell change?
Change the color whenever you replace the word in column A

[image]

Comment: What? You don't mean alternate, right, but rather alternate row color by unique items?

Comment: Yes @enderland alternate text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use de color formating with this formula:

```
=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A1<>"")/COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1&"")),2)=0
```

More info here: http://chandoo.org/forums/topic/yet-another-issue-of-alternating-colors

Comment: Whoa, I've come up with so many abominable hacks over the years because I didn't know about the sumproduct function. This is a great day!

Comment: @Kedamu, I found that that this formula is subject to unexpected MOD results for some combinations of cell changes, because of rounding errors. These can be avoided by wrapping the SUMPRODUCT in ROUND(...., 0).

Comment: I note that this formula doesn't work for the example given in the question (even with added ROUND function) because "Bar" occurs in two different groups - the solution depends on all repeated items being grouped together

Answer (score 2):

If you accept to have a hidden column, and do not want to use vba, the simplest thing to do would be to add a column (let's say a new column A, labels being now in B and values in C).
Column A will represent your target color. Set up conditional formatting on cells on columns B1 and C1 so that if A1 value is `TRUE` it they are grey (be careful that you get the value from A1 and not $A$1). Copy these B1 C1 cells downward.
Now to get the proper values in column A. You can set up A1 as being `TRUE` and A2 as being `=IF(B2=B1,A1,NOT(A1))`
Copy the formula from A2 downward. Cells in column B and C should now alternate color based on the change of label in column B.
You can now hide column A to make everything nicer.